# IntelliJ runs old version of tests and will not compile

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, multi-module

In the past there has been no issue updating a test and run it in IntelliJ. Now, even after a `File->Invalidate Caches->Invalidate and Restart` an older version of the test runs.

Running `mvn clean compile` before rerunning the tests in IntelliJ resolves the issue (`mvn clean test` also works as expected). An attempt to compile the project in IntelliJ results in a `java: package com.shared does not exist`. This is strange the project builds fine in Maven and IntelliJ does not catch any compile time errors with imports.

Could the error be related to the multi module project I recently created in Maven?

Comment: Try re-import from scratch: delete existing `.idea` directory and do the File | New | Project from Existing Sources... action. If issue remains, report at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new with a sample project and steps to reproduce and IDE logs attached (use Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data action).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File->Invalidate Caches->Invalidate and Restart
```

is not enough. Here are the steps to fix:

1. Delete .idea folder
2. `File -> Close Project`
3. Reopen the Project

Comment: This did not work for me.